# What is the maximum number of fields allowed for an index (ES 7)?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

We have an application around data visualization running purely from Elasticsearch 7. The number fields in some of the indices are increasing dynamically and we are expecting more than 15K fields for these indices. Also, we have applied a dynamic mapping template(for mapping text, keyword number, and email) for all dynamic fields.

We already know the settings "index.mapping.total_fields.limit" and increased the settings to "100000000".

1. What is the maximum limit on the number of fields in ES 7?
2. Any impacts other impacts?

Answer (score 2):

The limit of fields in an index is a soft-limit, it exists because having too many fields in an index impacts heavily on performance, storage and can lead to OOM errors.

You can have way more of 15k fields in an index, but this is not the ideal and you will have performance problems.